# Getting the surveys of a User

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have been wondering this for a while, given the following query

```
$survey = $user->surveys()
    ->where('survey_id', $survey)
    ->where('user_id', $user)->first();
```

If I'm asking the the surveys of a user. Is the

```
->where('user_id', $user)
```

necessary? 
It seems like I'm already asking the surveys of this user.

Comment: this would make sense if you are stopping users from looking up surveys that do not belong to them by supplying an arbitrary survey id?

Comment: How are your relations set up?

Answer (score 1):

Your `surveys` relation should already have automatically added the `->where('user_id', $user)` to the query if it's properly configured. So, you no longer need to add that part of the query yourself.

This is assuming your relationship is set up as in the code below, but it most likely is (I know the second and third parameter are optional and won't change anything behaviour-wise in this instance, I added them just for clarity here):

```
public function surveys()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Survey::class, 'survey_id', 'id'); 
}
```